# If I block someone from Gmail chat, will it block them on Google+?

Tags: google-plus, google-talk

Somebody I have added to my Google+ circles is now showing up as chattable in my Gmail chat sidebar. I don't want her to be able to see me as online whenever I've got a Gmail tab open - just when I'm using Google+.

But if I block her from regular Gmail chat, will it perform all the "block" functions on G+ as well (removing her from my circles, etc)? I want to continue our association on Google+ - I just don't want her to be able to chat with me on Gmail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According the [Google chat help](http://www.google.com/support/chat/bin/answer.py?answer=161879), no:

> Blocking someone from within the Chat list or a Chat mole does not also block the person in Google+. So, although they won't be able to chat with you, they'll still be in your Circles and be able to see your content. However, if you block the person in Google+, in addition to being removed from your circles and extended circles, they will also be unable to chat with you in any Google Chat property (i.e. Gmail, orkut, iGoogle).